# Reading properties file inside PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In Java Spark, any `spark.properties` file placed in the `/opt/spark/conf` folder seems to be loaded into my Spark environment as configuration options. However, the same behavior doesn't seem to work with `PySpark`. For example:

```py
# I see all the values when I do this!
with open('/opt/spark/conf/spark.properties', 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
    

# They are missing when I do this!
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll())
```

Comment: It should be a conf file, not a properties file. E.g. $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf

Comment: Maybe using the `SparConf` class is what you need.